# How to test the front end of a large software project

Tags: c#, gui, .net, unit-tests, software-testing

Scenario:

I've a very big software project (.NET, C#, WPF). Now I want to develop a perfect test environment for it. At the moment I’m using some NUnit unit tests. Now I need a good plan to implement frontend/GUI (coded UI?) tests. Which tools and which method would be the best to do that?

I have experience with the coded UI tests from Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate edition. But I think that’s no good solution because if my software project will change the frontend, you can waste the tests.

What do you think is the best method to simulate user interactions?

Comment: The codedui tests would not be wasted if the front-end changes. You can redo the test or modify the original code it generated.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending software – not howtos, manuals, best-practices, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) for the GUI.  It is a python/java scripted system for testing and driving GUI components that is cross platform and independent of the code of the GUI it is testing.

- Does **not** depend on item naming or IDs
- Does **not** require modification of the GUI code
- Does **not** use fixed positions
- Uses image recognition to identify GUI components & results, so:

  - If the program under test opens in a different screen position it is fine
  - If component IDs change it is fine
  - If components move it doesn't care
  - If components change look just modify the recognition item
- Can also send key presses
- Does require that all components are visually distinct - *which is a very good idea from a user point of view.*
- Free & Open Source